# Use global cache for openjpa 2

Tags: caching, global, openjpa

I am having 2 web app deployed in my server which are using same persistence unit. One is updating the object and other application is fetching it.
In both the web application openjpa cache is enabled on L2 level.
So, Changes done by web application one is not reflected on other web application. As both context is having their own open jpa cache.

How can i use the open jpa cache globally.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your L2 cache to one that supports distributed caching such as [Oracle Coherence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Instructions for setting this up with Coherence are available [here](http://ppoddar.blogspot.com/2009/10/l2-cache-in-jpa-20-and-openjpa-plug-in.html).  I can't find instructions online for Memcached, but I believe it is possible.